# Legend for a single point in Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm having some issues with the `legend` function. My code is as follows:

```
xax = logspace(1, 4, 1000);
R1 = sqrt(R11.*R21);
%freq and mag are vectors of length 300
loglog(freq, mag, 'k-');
hold on;    
loglog(xax, R1, 'r-');
loglog(f1, R1, 'bo');
loglog(f2, R1, 'bo');
legend('|Zvc|', 'R1', 'f1', 'f2');
```

However, the legend doesn't work as I'd expect. It shows a black line and red line for the first two, which is fine. But the last two points are shown as red lines rather than blue circles. Here's a picture that shows the incorrect legend:

[image]

`f1` and `f2` are scalar values that indicate intersection points.

Is there was a way to adjust my code so that the legend looks right?

Comment: Hard to debug when your code isn't runnable. What is the size of `sax` and `R1`? How many red lines are plotted by the second `loglog` function?

Comment: Well, the problem is I'm reading files for the points and doing calculations, so I didn't post all of the code. xax is a 1000-pt log-space vector, and R1 is just a single value. So a single red line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that `legend` is showing the last two plots as red lines is that your second `loglog` function is returning multiple handles. It looks like one line, but it's really multiple lines superimposed. Change `loglog(xax, R1, 'r-');` to `h=loglog(xax, R1, 'r-')` and you'll see. The `legend` function applies the strings you give to it to each handle in the current plot in the order that that they were created. This happens because `R1` is a scalar while `xax` is a vector. All of Matlab's plotting functions work this way.

Here's how I would change the relevant line:

```
loglog(xax, R1+zeros(size(xax)), 'r-');
```

Though if it's always a line, this would suffice:

```
xax = logspace(1, 4, 2);
loglog(xax, [R1 R1], 'r-');
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the handles actually. I used the last method you mentioned, and now the legends work fine.