# How do I make the legend lines match the line colors and width that I have set in MATLAB script?

Tags: matlab, legend

I'm having trouble making the lines of the legend match the line colors and width that I set in the code. I've tried many methods and read through the MATLAB help but I'm a non-programmer and I can't really understand what to do. I've also tried to figure out the solution by referring to some questions & answers on this site that were similar to my problem, then doing some trial and error to edit the legend, but as you can tell, it hasn't really worked out well, which is why I'm here. Could someone help me out please? Thank you very much!

This an image of my graph: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLq4p.jpg]

And my code is down below:

```
clf 
hold on
x = [-55:0.001:65];
y = log(abs(x-31)./(sqrt(x.^2+86)));
plot(x,y);
xlabel('x axis');
ylabel('y axis');
title('Graph of function');

a= -2.7742;
fa=log(abs(a-31)./(sqrt(a.^2+86)));
plot(a,fa,'s');

b= -10.39
fb=log(abs(b-31)./(sqrt(b.^2+86)));
plot(b,fb,'o');

bday=31
vertaxis= [-12:0.1:2]
plot(bday,vertaxis,'LineWidth',2,'color','red');

horizontalaxis=[-55:0.1:65]
horizontal=0
plot(horizontalaxis,horizontal,'LineWidth',2,'color','m');

plot([-55 -10.39],[-12 -12],'LineWidth',10,'color','c');
plot([-10.39 31],[-12 -12],'LineWidth',10,'color','y');
plot([31 65],[-12 -12],'LineWidth',10,'color','g');

legend('function','local maxima','Inflection point','vertical asymptote','horizontal asymptote','concave up','concave down','concave down','Location','Best');
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894638 for someone with the same problem.  The places where you are plotting a single value against a vector are what's causing the issue.

Comment: +1 for runnable (complete) code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Legend for a single point in Matlab plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894638/legend-for-a-single-point-in-matlab-plot)

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the following lines:

```
horizontalaxis=[-55:0.1:65]';
horizontal=zeros(length(horizontalaxis),1);
plot(horizontalaxis,horizontal,'LineWidth',2,'color','m'); 

vertaxis= [-12:0.1:2]';
bday=31.*ones(length(vertaxis),1);
plot(bday,vertaxis,'LineWidth',2,'color','red');
```

And it will be alright.

[image]

As already mentioned in the comments, the problem was, that you actually weren't plotting lines for your asymptotes, but more than a thousand single points. So your "concave" legends would appear a little late ;)

You can also see that your original plot has a dotted line and not a continuous one.

---

Edit:

```
plot([-55,65],[0,0],'LineWidth',2,'color','m'); 
plot([31,31],[-12,2],'LineWidth',2,'color','red');
```

would be enough actually. Like you did it below for the blue/yellow/green lines

Comment: Woah, thanks alot, thewaywewalk! I will try and input that into the script when I can get to the school lab. And yes, I did notice that my asymptote was dotted! I thought it was a default setting by MATLAB to differentiate between my lines so I didn't think it was an issue. Thank you for pointing out the problem, that explains why when I used the auto legend function I had a whole list of hundreds/thousands of data points! That probably explains why my figure and legend takes so long to be processed too right?

Comment: yes, because the "autolegend" would have been huge with about 1400 elements.